# Pl/sql Script to return last two digits of MobileNumber of datatype numeric

Tags: sql, oracle

Here the basic fields look like :

```
7045069949,
9449087591
```

Output be like :

Last two digits of fields:

```
49,
91
```

Any suggestion from your side ..

Answer (score 2):

Since it's numeric, you may use remainder of dividing by 100 (modulo);

```
create table test_t(num_col numeric);

insert into test_t values(7045069949);
insert into test_t values(9449087591);

select num_col, mod(num_col, 100)
   from test_t;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecedb20a102c720eb1a4dceac362c232)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT col, SUBSTR(col, -2, LENGTH(col)) AS last_two
FROM yourTable;
```

You could also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\d{2}$') AS last_two
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I'm using this syntax :SUBSTR(\"CustomMobile\",8) WHERE LENGTH(\"CustomMobile\")=10;       But output fields are getting like 949,91 and also last digit in mobile number . can you tell me why it is happening ?

Comment: This is not what my answers is saying.

Comment: For this syntax :SET \"CustomMobile\" = SUBSTR(\"CustomMobile\",-2) WHERE LENGTH(\"CustomMobile\")=10;for this input fields : 9211004700,9333180302  i am getting output like : 0,2 why before zero is not reflecting ?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the simplest option is just `substr(value, -2)`, e.g.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '7045069949' from dual union all
  3     select '9449087591' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         substr(col, -2) result
  7  from test;

COL        RE
---------- --
7045069949 49
9449087591 91

SQL>
```